# Click event for label in amCharts

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I am working on `amCharts` Donut chart.

Following is the script for creating the chart.

**JS**

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
  "type": "pie",
  "pullOutDuration":0.5,
 "pullOutRadius": "5",
 "theme": "light",
 "dataProvider": [ {
   "title": "Aaa",
   "value": 10,
 }, {
   "title": "Bbb",
   "value": 10,
 },{
   "title":"Ccc",
   "value":10,
 },{
   "title":"Ddd",
   "value":10,
 },{
   "title":"Eee",
   "value":10,
 }],
 "titleField": "title",
 "valueField": "value",
 "labelRadius": 50,

 "radius": "35%",
 "innerRadius": "85%",
 "labelText": "[[title]]",
 "export": {
   "enabled": true
 },
 "baseColor":"#7a4436",
 "pullOutOnlyOne":true,
 "startEffect":"easeOutSine",
 "pullOutEffect":"easeOutSine",
 "showBalloon":false,
 "listeners": [{
     "event": "clickSlice",
     "method": function(e) {
          var dp = e.dataItem.dataContext;
          alert(dp.title + ':'+dp.value)

          e.chart.validateData();
     }
   }]
});
```

[image]

I am able to give click event listener for each slice of the chart.

But ***I would like to add a click event for label of each slice***. So here in my example click event for the labels `Aaa`, `Bbb`, etc..

**Edit**

or how to give an `anchor` tag to these Labels??

[**Here is the working fiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/ynzwu1en/1/)

Comment: What is the purpose of `e.chart.validateData();` in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally the listener for `clickSlice` is only attached to the `wedge` and the little `tick` to the label, but not to the label itself.

You can do this manually though, using this code piece:

```
chart.addListener("init", function() {
    var d = chart.chartData;
    for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
        d[i].label.node.style.pointerEvents = "auto";
        chart.addEventListeners(d[i].labelSet, d[i]);
    }
});
```

As the labels have the [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) style assigned to `none` automatically, you have to change this back, so the mouse-events can be registered. Then you can add a listener manually to the `svg` element using a method provided by the chart.

You have to do this after the chart was initialized. However if you want to remain the `e.chart.validateData()` call in your handler, you have to listen on a different event (like [`drawn`](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmPieChart#drawn)).

If the purpose of `e.chart.validateData()` was to stop a slice to be pulled out, the better way to do this would be using [`pullOutRadius: 0`](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmPieChart#pullOutRadius)

Here's a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ztyv37bu/).

Answer (score 0):

Updated simple answer for v4:

```
const yAxisLabel = mySeries.bullets.push(new am4charts.LabelBullet());
yAxisLabel.label.interactionsEnabled = false;
```